# nonzero return code although find -exec rm works

Tags: linux, shell

I'm on a linux system I wonder what is wrong with the following execution of find:

```
mkdir a && touch a/b                      
find . -name a -type d -exec echo '{}' \; 
./a
find . -name a -type d -exec rm -r '{}' \;
find: `./a': No such file or directory
```

The invocation of echo is just for testing purposes.  I would expect the last command to remove the directory './a' entirely and return 0.  Instead it removes the directory and generates the error message. To repeat, it does remove the directory! What is going on?

Comment: Why did you add the tag 'find'?  It says "DO NOT use this tag".  I removed it again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`rm` executes without a problem. The issue is that `find` is confused, since it knew the directory `./a` was there, it tries to visit that directory to look for directories named `a`. However, find cannot enter the directory, since it was already removed.

One way to avoid this is to do

```
find -name a -type d | xargs rm -r
```

This will let the find move along before the `rm` command is executed. Or, you can simply ignore the error in your original command.

Comment: I know, but I don't like to call xargs because it forks yet another process.  Anyway, your hint solved the issue! Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest just using the `-delete` primary instead, e.g. `find . -name a -type d -delete`.

Comment: @Adam -delete seems to work only for individual files, not recursively on directories.

Comment: `xargs` will generally fork fewer processes because it will only execute one `rm` (or several if the command line is very long). It's basically better for all cases except when there is less than 2 directories to delete, and then it shouldn't matter that much anyway.

Comment: And also, if there is nothing to delete, `rm -r` will cry with 'missing operand'. You can avoid it with `xargs -r rm -r`.

Answer (score 6):

Based on epsalon's comment the solution is to use the -depth option which causes the deeper files to be visited first.

```
find . -depth -name a -type d -exec rm -r '{}' \;
```

does the trick.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Actually, you original code works faster than `-depth` and you can just ignore the errors.

Answer (score 5):

If performance is an issue, use -prune in order to prevent find from descending into directories named "a":

```
find . -name a -type d -prune -exec rm -r '{}' \;
```